# How to override php file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override the PHP file in Magento 2. but several problems occur on override methods.

so put the correct overriding method.

Comment: Could you please clarify which file exactly you'd like to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overide any file, you need to below code in your module's `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="YOUR_ORIGNAL_FILE_PATH" type="Extension\Vendor\CUSTOMFilePath"/>
</config>
```

Then create custom file on given path into the `type` attribute value.